# На чём писать десктопное(настольное) приложение, если оно включает карту с множеством объектов, а значит требуется производительный рендеринг?

Tags: java, node.js, typescript, electron, desktop

Идея такова: нужно написать десктопное приложение, которое включает в себя карту(OpenstreetMap). Бэкэнд на Java. Рассматриваю вариант Electron в связке с Angular, также читал про nodeGUI - вроде бы производительнее, но полной картины я не понял, как это работает. Раньше писал на Swing. Что из этого будет лучше или может есть более подходящие варианты?

Comment: Кроссплатформенное? И что значит "производительный рендеринг"?

Comment: Скорее кроссплатформенное, но другие варианты тоже рассматриваются. Про рендеринг не совсем верно озвучил - нужен быстрый рендеринг, быстрая перерисовка при движении карты.